# Rails, deal with alternative camelized classname

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a big old Rails app (4.1) that has an issue where there are a group of related classes that use two different camelizations. For example's sake:

```
class LegacyStuff; end
class Legacystuff; end
```

People on the team trip over this all the time, and I'd really like to just nuke the ones that are like `Legacystuff` and camelize them `LegacyStuff` which is more widely used in the app and more consistent with camelizing words.

The major problem is, renaming this has turned into a huge pain because one of the classes involved is polymorphic, so there's a table like: `gizmos` that has a lot of records with type `Legacystuff`.

If we migrate to change that, the app is going to have to have downtime during that deploy or else the workers will start crashing as the database changes aren't compatible with the old code.

Is there a way to tell rails polymorphism to use the string `Legacystuff` to point to the class `LegacyStuff`?

Or alternatively is there a clean migration path to avoid the downtime?

Second, and much less important, all the old stuff has file and foldernames like `legacystuff_controller` and `views/legacystuff`, whereas changing the camelization requires renaming all that for the autoloader to work?

I expect to just rename the stuff, but out of curiosity is there any way to tell the autoloader about the existence of an irregular class, so that the renaming could be avoided?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after trying a lot of other things, I found that just doing:

```
# legacy_stuff.rb
class LegacyStuff
  # actual class goes here
end

# legacystuff.rb
Legacystuff = LegacyStuff
```

Was enough of a bandaid to let me make the migration, rename all the STI columns, then do a second deploy to remove the temp class.

Not saying I would recommend this to anyone else, but, it worked.